# Access Token validation fails using AWS Cognito, NestJS and Passport

Tags: jwt, nestjs, amazon-cognito, passport.js, access-token

I've been trying to configure token validation with AWS Cognito and NestJS. I've configured the JwtStrategy as following the many examples on the internet but the token validation continues to fail.

Here is the Jwt Strategy Class.

```
import { passportJwtSecret } from 'jwks-rsa';
import { ConfigService } from '@nestjs/config';

import { ExtractJwt, Strategy } from 'passport-jwt';
import { PassportStrategy } from '@nestjs/passport';
import { Injectable } from '@nestjs/common';


@Injectable()
export class JwtStrategy extends PassportStrategy(Strategy) {
  constructor(private readonly configService: ConfigService) {

    super({
      secretOrKeyProvider: passportJwtSecret({
        cache: true,
        rateLimit: true,
        jwksRequestsPerMinute: 3,
        jwksUri: `https://cognito-idp.${configService.get(
          'AWS_REGION'
        )}.amazonaws.com/${configService.get(
          'AWS_COGNITO_USER_POOL_ID',
        )}/.well-known/jwks.json`,
      }),

      jwtFromRequest: ExtractJwt.fromAuthHeaderAsBearerToken(),
      audience: configService.get('AWS_COGNITO_CLIENT_ID'),
      issuer: `https://cognito-idp.${configService.get(
        'AWS_REGION',
      )}.amazonaws.com/${configService.get('AWS_COGNITO_USER_POOL_ID')}`,
      algorithms: ['RS256'],
    });
  }

  async validate(payload: any) {
    return { userId: payload.sub, username: payload.username };
  }
}
```

**Resolution:**

After some long debugging of the passport functionality in the verify.js file, I found the following piece of code that checks if the audience matches:

```
if (options.audience) {
      const audiences = Array.isArray(options.audience) ? options.audience : [options.audience];
      const target = Array.isArray(payload.aud) ? payload.aud : [payload.aud];

      const match = target.some(function (targetAudience) {
        return audiences.some(function (audience) {
          return audience instanceof RegExp ? audience.test(targetAudience) : audience === targetAudience;
        });
      });

      if (!match) {
        return done(new JsonWebTokenError('jwt audience invalid. expected: ' + audiences.join(' or ')));
      }
    }
```

**The problem is that the access token issued by AWS Cognito does not set the aud property.** You can check the documentation here: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/amazon-cognito-user-pools-using-the-access-token.html

**So if you want to use the access token issued by Cognito you need to remove the audience property from the JWT Strategy Class:**

````
@Injectable()
export class JwtStrategy extends PassportStrategy(Strategy) {
  constructor(private readonly configService: ConfigService) {

    super({
      secretOrKeyProvider: passportJwtSecret({
        cache: true,
        rateLimit: true,
        jwksRequestsPerMinute: 3,
        jwksUri: `https://cognito-idp.${configService.get(
          'AWS_REGION'
        )}.amazonaws.com/${configService.get(
          'AWS_COGNITO_USER_POOL_ID',
        )}/.well-known/jwks.json`,
      }),

      jwtFromRequest: ExtractJwt.fromAuthHeaderAsBearerToken(),
      issuer: `https://cognito-idp.${configService.get(
        'AWS_REGION',
      )}.amazonaws.com/${configService.get('AWS_COGNITO_USER_POOL_ID')}`,
      algorithms: ['RS256'],
    });
  }

  async validate(payload: any) {
    return { userId: payload.sub, username: payload.username };
  }
}```
````

Answer (score 0):

I was wondering why the tutorials work but not on my machine, turn out I need to remove both the audience and issuer fields.